# react native won't fetch locally on emulator

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a problem with iOS and Android. I'm using the following code:

```
fetch('https://192.168.0.143:3000/auth/signin').then(() => console.log('ok')).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This is simplified offcourse, but you will get the point.

This does not work, I get an error with "network request failed". When I test it in postman, it works! also https://localhost:3000/auth/signin works in postman (192.168.0.143 is my local IP), but not through react-native fetch.

I've created a self signed key, and my node js server code is the following:

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app).listen(3000,
() => console.log('listening...'))
```

server.key and server.cert are both in the folder where app.js (nodejs) also is. And the server is running.

Is there a problem with my self signed certificate? Or where can I locate my problem?

**EDIT**

I've created a new part of my node.js-script:

```
const test = (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('OK').end()
}
app.get('/test', test)
```

So when I visit https://localhost:3000/test on safari on my ios simulator, I see "OK". But the network request still keeps failing in my app. I think it has something to do with my self-signed certificate, but I don't know the exact problem.

Comment: are you using express to handle https traffic?

Comment: no require('https')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you could check would be, test to ping the local server `https://192.168.0.143:3000` from your Simulator/Physical device. You shall get response from there.

On **iOS**, you might need to have the following at your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

On **Android**, If you're using `react-native-pinch` for my Project, you have to use HTTP protocol for the file `HttpUtil.java`. By default, it's all on HTTPS protocol.

Also, you might want to include your workstation's IP at network_security_config.xml file under `android/app/main/res/xml/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">YOUR IP ADDRESS</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
        <!-- Modify the to your local IP address to allow app deployment on Android Pie -->
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: when I go to "https://localhost:3000/auth/signin" on safari on the ios simulator, I see "Cannot GET /auth/signin", so there is a response. But fetch() keeps failing. BTW, the NSAppTransportSecurity is already in my info.plist-file I see, but it still won't work.

Comment: No? You are not suppose to get "Cannot GET /auth/signin". Instead, your expected response should shown on the website when you trigger the GET Api. Whatever's coded on your `res.send()` in at your local server should be shown on your website.

Comment: Also, make sure you you have your local mock server running on terminal. Since you are using node.js.. it should be `nodemon app.js` (change app.js to any file if you are not using app.js as entry point)

Comment: I've edited my question. I've added some new code to test the connection. BTW, with nodemon installed it's also not working (same error).

Comment: In my case, no self-signed cert is involved. You need to run your mock server with the command I shared.. the terminal should stay running on port 3000.

Comment: I've deleted the self-signed certificate and indeed, it works now! I'm just running it over http now. It's for testing so I think it does not really matter. Thank you for your help @TommyLeong! I really appreciate it!